# ASP.NET add-migration generates empty migration on IdentityModels.cs changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been making some changes to the IdentityModels.cs. Mostly just ignoring a couple of fields and renaming the table from "AspNetUsers" to "Users". But after I save those changes, build the project and generate the migration, it's just empty..

The changes I've made to IdentityModels.cs are as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Bestelling> Bestellingen { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I've basically added 1 line here, the public virtual List.

And then I also added:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Ignore(c => c.EmailConfirmed)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumber)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnabled)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEndDateUtc);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
    }
```

As I said, just to ignore some of the fields and rename the table to Users.
Afterwards I just saved it all, built the project and typed

```
add-migration database-v2
```

And after that

```
update-database
```

But nothing happens, since the migration looks like this:

```
namespace Eindopdracht.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class databasev2 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Now in other models I've added for example this bit:

```
public virtual DbSet<Klant> Klants { get; set; }
```

But I don't have a clue what to add in IdentityModels.cs to make it all come together.

I've looked through other questions here on Stack Overflow but I can't really find a solution.

**EDIT**

Contents of my ApplicationDbContext():

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DatabankEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(c => c.EmailConfirmed)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumber)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnabled)
                                           .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEndDateUtc);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
    }
}
```

**EDIT II**

This is my Configuration.cs:

```
namespace Eindopdracht.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Eindopdracht.Models.DatabankBestellijn>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Eindopdracht.Models.DatabankBestellijn context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
}
```

I changed the

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Eindopdracht.Models.DatabankBestellijn>
```

bit to:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Eindopdracht.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
```

And it works! However I cant update the database now because it says that these tables already exist, is there a way to enforce it?

```
update-database -Force
```

Doesn't seem to be the way to go.

**Final Edit**

Changing the configuration.cs file and making the minor changes in IdentityModels.cs was the solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in your `OnModelCreating` method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().
```

You're referencing **IdentityUser** where you should be using **ApplicationUser**

So your `OnModelCreating` becomes

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(c => c.EmailConfirmed)
                                       .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumber)
                                       .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                       .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
                                       .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnabled)
                                       .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEndDateUtc);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes just like you said, but the migration is still empty.. I just have to build after the changes and then add-migration right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.
If there are no changes to the database since the migration was last generated, there will be no migration to generate.

Comment: Well the migration was generated in the Migrations directory, but it was still empty like the one before that..

Comment: Please can you edit your question and show your DbContext class?

Comment: i'm wondering if your _MigrationHistory table has got in a mess - try giving the migration a different name - `add-migration database-v3` for example

Comment: I thought so too at first since I saw it in different questions, but it's still empty.. I've looked through many other solutions but nothing seems to work and it's probably something small and silly :p

Comment: I've discovered something that might be the cause for the issue.. I'll place it in another edit